# Existence and uniqueness of orthonormal coframes having zero divergence

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, gauge-theory

Given a differential manifold with smooth metric g, does there exist an orthonormal coframe $e^a$ such that $d^*e^a$=0

a. everywhere or almost everywhere

b. locally/globally, and

c. is it unique?

Here, $d^*$ denotes the codifferential (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Codifferential). The closest reference I could find is a physics reference related to gauge fixing tetrad fields (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07571.pdf) and does not appear to address the above existence and uniqueness question.

A reference addressing the questions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you computed some standard examples?

Comment: Well, I believe for Euclidean space such a coframing exists globally but is not unique. So, such a coframing should exist locally on any smooth manifold. The global question probably depends on the Euler characteristic, but I am not particularly smart. Hence the question.